# How to fixed this error in Contact Form & multi step

Tags: wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I`m using Contact form Multi Step plugin in wordpress, i have 5 form and everytime I press the previous button it will not redirect to the previous form

Hi guys Everytime I press the previous button it has an error:

Error:

```
    {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and 
    request method","data":{"status":404}}
```

Additional:
And Everytime i submit the thank you message appear

Comment: By saying previous button, is that a previous button of the form or browser back button? Does your browser's address bar's URL get changed?

Comment: this is my previous button code [previous "Previous"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer below is an unofficial fix of a bug with Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms v2.1 on WordPress v4.7.5.

The plugin does not work properly anymore according to the [author's update](https://mymonkeydo.com/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/).

> UPDATE:  This plugin still works as expected for most people, but it does not for some.

To fix this, you will have to edit some codes of the plugin.

Update this function in `wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/form-tags/module-back.php`.

```
/**
 * Handle the back form shortcode.
 */
function cf7msm_back_shortcode_handler( $tag ) {
    if (!class_exists('WPCF7_Shortcode') || !function_exists('wpcf7_form_controls_class'))
        return;
    $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );

    $class = wpcf7_form_controls_class( $tag->type );

    $atts = array();

    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
    $atts['id'] = $tag->get_id_option();
    $atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option( 'tabindex', 'int', true );

    $value = isset( $tag->values[0] ) ? $tag->values[0] : '';
    $previous_url = isset( $tag->values[1] ) ? $tag->values[1] : '.';
    if ( empty( $value ) ) {
        if ( $tag->type == 'previous') {
            $value = __( 'Previous', 'contact-form-7-multi-step-module' );
        }
        else {
            //using old version
            $value = __( 'Back', 'contact-form-7-multi-step-module' );
        }
    }

    $atts['type'] = 'button';
    $atts['value'] = $value;
    $atts['href'] = $previous_url;

    $atts = wpcf7_format_atts( $atts );

    $html = sprintf( '<input %1$s />', $atts );

    return $html;
}
```

And update 1 line in `wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/resources/cf7msm.js` changing

```
window.location.href = val[step_field.val()];
```

to

```
window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
```

Finally, you need to change how you insert `[previous]` tag in contact form. After making the changes above, the `[previous]` tag works like so.

```
[previous "Button Label" "URL of previous step"]
```